# Allow null table in Group

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, null, linq-group

I'm trying to write a LINQ query in C# expression to get an overview for a Purchase Order which includes a table `TblPODetails` with the list of items in the purchase order. I want to get every line item in this table and then add to it the total amount of items which have been received which is recorded in the table `TblPOReceipts`.
If there is no items received then `TblPOReceipts` shows null and the query returns 0 results.

How can I allow nulls in the `TblPOReceipts` and still get the rest of my results from `TblPODetails`?

This is my query:

```
from podetail in TblPODetails
from pricebook in TblPriceBooks.Where(x => x.ItemID == podetail.ItemID).DefaultIfEmpty()
from receipt in TblPOReceipts.Where(x => x.ItemID ==podetail.ItemID).DefaultIfEmpty()

where podetail.PONumber == 4707
where receipt.PONumber == 4707

group new { receipt, podetail, pricebook } by new {pricebook, podetail, receipt.QuantityReceived } into g

select new {
    g.Key.podetail.ItemDescription,
    TotalReceived = g.Sum (x => x.receipt.QuantityReceived),
    QuantityPosted = g.Where (x => x.receipt.Posted == true).Sum (x => x.receipt.QuantityReceived),
    g.Key.podetail.ItemID,
    g.Key.podetail.QuantityOrdered,
    g.Key.podetail.ProjectedCost,
    g.Key.podetail.TotalProjectedCost,
    g.Key.pricebook.BaseCost,
    g.Key.pricebook.ItemURL
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake in my query as I was using:

```
where receipt.PONumber == 4707
```

which was null and therefore returning no results.

I have fixed this as such:

```
where receipt.PONumber == null || receipt.PONumber == 4707
```

I have also cast the sum as an int.

```
    TotalReceived = (int?)g.Sum (x => x.receipt.QuantityReceived),
    QuantityPosted = (int?)g.Where (x => x.receipt.Posted == true).Sum (x => x.receipt.QuantityReceived),
```